# How can i fetch data/rows from Stored Procedure SQL Server in PHP, i tried many ways but still doesn't work

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures, fetch, sqlsrv

I need help .. I'm trying to fetch rows from Stored Procedure.
but it nothing shows at all in loop ..

I don't know where is my mistake and I hope someone can help me to find it out and teach me the best and good way to fetch data from SP SQL Server.

Here is my code in PHP:

```
$connectionInfo = array( "UID"=>"XXXX", "PWD"=>"xxxxxx", "Database"=>"xxxxx" );
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn === false ){
    echo "Could not connect to server.\n";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

$now_date  = date('Ymd H:i:s');
$kode_menu = trim($get_menu_n_sub['Kd_menu']);
$kode_sub  = trim($get_menu_n_sub['kd_sub']);
  
 --> Here is how i execute my stored procedure --- 
$get_data  = "exec SP_MCM_CheckInputSchedule '$now_date', '$kode_sub', '$kode_menu', '$akses'";
  
$check_time    = sqlsrv_query($conn,$get_data);
if (!$check_time) { ----------------- The if Here shows Me Good
    echo 'failed';
}else{
    echo 'Good'; <-- even if it return 'Good' but nothing shows from while loop --
    while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($check_time,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row;
    }
}
die;
```

I treid to fetch using many ways, but nothing work. How I can echo or display the values or the records of stored procedure? Here is the output if I execute the SP in SQL Server:

[image: here is the output if i execute the SP in SQL Server]

And here is my SP in my SQL Server that I call/execute from PHP script:

```
USE [DB_Name]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[SP_MCM_CheckInputSchedule]    
Script Date: 17/04/2023 16.53.19 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_MCM_CheckInputSchedule](@dWaktu as 
datetime, @kode_sub as int, @kode_menu as int, @akses as 
varchar(10))
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
-- SET NOCOUNT ON;
declare @kode_jadwal char(5);
declare @nama_jadwal char(30);
declare @white_list bit;
declare @boleh bit;
declare @toleran bit;
declare @tgl date;
declare @jam time;

set @tgl = CAST(@dWaktu as date)
set @jam = CAST(@dWaktu as time)

create table #list_table ( kode_jadwal char(5), nama_jadwal 
char(30), boleh bit, toleran bit )

select a.kode_jadwal, a.nama_jadwal, a.white_list, d.by_datetime, 
d.waktu_awal, d.waktu_akhir,
cast(d.waktu_awal as date) as tgl_awal, cast(d.waktu_akhir as date) 
as tgl_akhir,
cast(d.waktu_awal as time) as jam_awal, cast(d.waktu_akhir as time) 
as jam_akhir,
(case when d.waktu_toleran is null then d.waktu_akhir else 
d.waktu_toleran end) as waktu_toleran,
(case when d.waktu_toleran is null then cast(d.waktu_akhir as date) 
else cast(d.waktu_toleran as date) end) as tgl_toleran,
(case when d.waktu_toleran is null then cast(d.waktu_akhir as time) 
else cast(d.waktu_toleran as time) end) as jam_toleran
into #all_available
from mcmjadwalh as a
inner join mcmjadwald_menu as b on a.kode_jadwal=b.kode_jadwal
inner join mcmjadwald_user as c on c.kode_jadwal=a.kode_jadwal
inner join mcmjadwald_tgl as d on d.kode_jadwal=a.kode_jadwal
where b.kd_menu=@kode_menu and b.kd_submenu=@kode_sub and 
c.role_id=@akses

-- White List
select distinct a.kode_jadwal, a.nama_jadwal, 1 as boleh, 0 as 
toleran
into #white_list
from #all_available as a
where a.white_list=1 and ((a.by_datetime=1 and (@tgl between 
a.tgl_awal and a.tgl_akhir) and 
(@jam between a.jam_awal and a.jam_akhir)) or
(a.by_datetime=0 and (@dWaktu between a.waktu_awal and 
a.waktu_akhir)))

-- Black List
select distinct a.kode_jadwal, a.nama_jadwal, 0 as boleh, 0 as 
toleran
into #black_list
from #all_available as a
where a.white_list=0 and ((a.by_datetime=1 and (@tgl between 
a.tgl_awal and a.tgl_akhir) and 
(@jam between a.jam_awal and a.jam_akhir)) or
(a.by_datetime=0 and (@dWaktu between a.waktu_awal and 
a.waktu_akhir)))

-- Toleran List
select distinct a.kode_jadwal, a.nama_jadwal, 0 as boleh, 1 as 
toleran
into #toleran_list
from #all_available as a
where a.white_list=1 and (
(a.by_datetime=1 and 
(((@tgl between a.tgl_awal and a.tgl_toleran) and (@jam between 
a.jam_akhir and a.jam_toleran)) or
 ((@tgl between a.tgl_akhir and a.tgl_toleran) and (@jam between 
a.jam_awal and a.jam_toleran)))
) or
(a.by_datetime=0 and (@dWaktu between a.waktu_akhir and 
a.waktu_toleran)))

-- Unlist
select distinct a.kode_jadwal, a.nama_jadwal, (case a.white_list 
                                                when 0 then 1 
                                                when 1 then 0 end) 
as boleh, 0 as toleran
into #unlist
from #all_available as a
left join #white_list as b on a.kode_jadwal=b.kode_jadwal
left join #black_list as c on a.kode_jadwal=c.kode_jadwal
left join #toleran_list as d on a.kode_jadwal=d.kode_jadwal
where b.kode_jadwal is null and c.kode_jadwal is null and 
d.kode_jadwal is null

-- Gabungan
select top 1 *
into #hasil
from (  select a.kode_jadwal, a.nama_jadwal, a.boleh, a.toleran
        from ( select *
                from #white_list as a1
                union all
                select *
                from #black_list as b1
                union all
                select *
                from #toleran_list as c1
                union all
                select *
                from #unlist as d1 ) as a ) as b
order by b.boleh, b.toleran, b.kode_jadwal

if @@ROWCOUNT=0
    begin
        Select 0 as boleh, 0 as toleran, '' as kode_jadwal, '' as nama_jadwal, 
        'Tidak ada Jadwal yang di assign utk Role ID dan Menu ID ini' as Keterangan
    end
else
    begin
        select a.boleh, a.toleran, a.kode_jadwal, a.nama_jadwal,
        (case a.toleran when 1 then 'Masuk Batas Toleransi' 
            else (case a.boleh when 1 then 'Valid' 
                    else 'Melanggar Aturan Jadwal' end) end) as Keterangan
        from #hasil as a
    end

--drop table #hasil;
drop table #unlist;
drop table #white_list;
drop table #black_list;
drop table #toleran_list;
drop table #all_available;
drop table #list_table;

END;
```

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is **dangerous**. It is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Always, *always, **always*** parametrise your code. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: Also the prefix `sp_` is reserved, by Microsoft, for **S**pecial / **S**ystem **P**rocedures. It should *not* be used for User Procedures. Doing so comes with a performance cost and the risk of your Procedure simply not working one day after an update/upgrade. Either use a different prefix or (possibly better) no prefix at all. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Comment: thanks @ThomA i will parametrise to be safe from SQL injection attacks .

Comment: `echo $row;` probably isn't going to work, you need to iterate the array.

Comment: do u mean i have to use Print_r() or Var_dumb ? @Charlieface

Comment: Have you tried printing out the values of `$now_date`, `$kode_sub`, `$kode_menu` and `$akses` to confirm that they match expected the inputs? e.g.: If you need to match the date format that you used in SSMS consider using `$now_date = date('Ymd');` instead of `$now_date = date('Ymd H:i:s');`

Comment: i used date('Ymd H:i:s') because i need the date with time .. not only date .. coz it really necessary .. how can i do it ? any ideas ?

Comment: regards $now_date(value = 20230417 20:06:00,kode_sub(value = 0),kode_menu(value= 5) and akses(value = Leader). and in my SP it will defined as Datetime, integer, integer and varchar . @AlwaysLearning

Comment: Sqlserver datetime format is `Y-m-d H:i:s`, right? This is a typo question? Not `Ymd H:i:s`.

Comment: i've tried using `Y-m-d H:i:s` still the same thing . no rows showed up when i `echo or Print_r or Var_vump` .. @mickmackusa

Comment: When you run it in your RDBMS you wrote a space after the stored procedures name.  Did you try with a space in your code? Prepared statements feel like a wise choice here.  Related content: [php - how execute a sqlsrv stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65017555/2943403) and [How to execute a stored procedure in php using sqlsrv and "?" style parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31575135/2943403)

Comment: yes i wrote it with space in my php code .. i will try to follow one of ur links that u just shared.. and i hope it can help .. @mickmackusa

Comment: (I don't have any experience with sqlserver.) More relevant pages: [execute stored procedure using sqlsrv in php 7+](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57514772/2943403) and [Can't Execute Stored Procedure with sqlsrv in php](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57514772/2943403)

Comment: usually it works with me but i don't know this one it doesn't. it's kinda weird but im sure there is something wrong in my code  but i didn't notice it till now .. Thanks for ur references @mickmackusa . im still try to follow it

Comment: @Jafar, four notes: 1) Put `SET NOCOUNT ON` as first line in your stored procedure; 2) Always use parameteres in your statements to prevent possible SQL injection issues; 3) Where do you assign a value of `$akses` variable and 4) Try to pass the date value using an unambiguous datetime format (my experience is summarized [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55276287/php7-3-sqlsrv-format-of-datetime-different-when-query-and-store/55286218#55286218)).

Comment: thanks a lot @Zhorov .. i just uncomment `SET NOCOUNT ON` and finally the records showed up .. thanks again. i hope u can post ur comment as a post so i can make it as an answer